# Threaded programming in Objective-C, for sending request to a web server

Tags: iphone, multithreading, web-services, ios4

I'm in this kind of situation... I want to patch 100 different web requests, but it's separated in three different functions:

```
-(void)functionMain {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        [self sendRequestToServer];
}
```

So that first function will basically send request to some URL and wait for it to finish...

```
-(void)sendRequestToServer {
    [request sendRequest:mAddress];
    [request didFinishSelector:@"refreshAddress"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

This function above will do the actual sending of the address.

```
-(void)refreshAddress {
    NSString *result = [request getResponse];
    mAddress = [result getTheNextAddress];
    [self refreshDisplay];
}
```

Now this will set mAddress to the next web address. So I got a lot of this, and apparently one request takes a bit of time (around 600 ms), but if you notice in the main loop in `functionMain`, I don't have any mechanism to see whether `refreshAddress` has finished doing its job, because it it hasn't then I'll only be sending request with the same address over and over.

I tried using a boolean variable to guard the loop, but it doesn't look like it's working... Is there any graceful way to do this? I'm not sure what should I look for.. I don't know if `NSOperation` or `NSThread` will help me.

EDIT: As I mentioned in the comment, this is probably more like I'm having a multi-threading situation here (to be exact this might be 100 threads) that I want to make into only a single thread.

EDIT: So what I really want is like this (suppose the loop is only 3):

```
functionMain(i = 0) -> 
sendRequestToServer
```

Then we wait until that finishes, then we have this:

```
refreshAddress (mAddress has been set to something else now) -> 
functionMain (i = 1) -> 
sendRequestToServer
```

Once again:

```
refreshAddress (mAddress has been set to something else now) -> 
functionMain (i = 2, finished)
```

Very very sorry if I can't describe the problem more clearly... I wish I can write better english and can describe things clearer!

Comment: I don't see you doing any threading here.  You also appear to be re-using a request object before it's finished doing the previous one.  You probably need 1 request and one maddress PER request.  It also appears that you intend the result one one to be used as the address in the next, so how can threading help here?

Comment: So in that request object that I'm using, the method [request didFinishSelector:method] will wait until the request finishes, then call the method that I specified. So maybe what this is is really a multithreaded program that I want to make into a single thread program using some kind of lock...

Comment: but you appear to invoke the same request object to start processing the next request from maddress before the previous has finished and yielded the next maddress, and using the same request object is likely to end up in failure.

Comment: Please can you write down a short explanation of what would happen if the loop were only 3 long - describing sample urls and return values, and how you see those flowing from one iteration to the next.

Comment: Sorry Alex if that was not clear enough! I've tried rephrasing the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly I'm not following you here but if you want them to happen one after the other you should use a synchronous request in [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

Comment: Ok, that sort of answers my question... But I read somewhere that in iphones it's a very bad idea to do things synchronously right? Your solution works quite well, but there's a reasonable amount of delay before the phone refreshed its display.

Comment: @the_great_monkey - Yes it would if you do it from the main thread as it blocks the UI. You still have to do this from another thread, and then update the UI when the web service returns and then just call the next one synchronously. Makes sense? :)

Comment: Ah... ok. Should I be looking at NSOperation or NSThread for this? Thanks so much.